# Find fake rocks from $2\cdot n$ rocks

Tags: combinatorics

I have $2\cdot n$ rocks, some of them are fake, in other words heavy. I have a balance scale. All fake rocks have the same weight.I want to prove that I can find their $number$ with $n+1$ weighting.

I tried to prove this using induction. If $n=1$ I can do it (assuming there is at least a real rock) with $1$ weighting. I assume it is true for $n$, and for $n+1$ I did so: $2(n+1)$ rocks I divided into $n+1$ groups in each $2$ rocks, and with $n+1$ weighting found those groups, that have at least a fake rock. But I can't know their exactly count. Please help me.

Comment: Do all the real rocks have the same weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** If we find a pair of a real rock and a fake one, we can measure $2m$ rocks with $m$ weightings.

Do you see why?

Now, with this in mind, let's try to solve the problem.

We start by picking two rocks and weighting one against the other. If we get a difference, we know that one is real and the other is fake, and we can measure the remaining rocks with only $n-1$ weightings ($n$ in total).

If they are similar, we start weighting them against other pairs of distinct rocks until we get a difference.

If we don't, then they are all real (assuming that at least one is), and we only used $n$ weightings. Otherwise, let $k$ be the number of weightings needed until we get a difference.

We know that the first $2k$ rocks are similar. From the result of the last weighting, we discover whether they are all fake or all real. We use one extra weighting to check if the last pair is composed of similar or different rocks.

In any case, we can now take a pair of a real and a fake rock to measure the remaining ones.

In the end, we have used one weighting for the first pair, $k$ to find a non-equivalent one, one more on the last, and $n-k-1$ to measure the rest of the set, totalling $1 + k + 1 + (n-k-1) = n + 1$.

Comment: Please explain why we can say, that If we find a pair of a real rock and a fake one, we can measure 2m rocks with m weightings.

Comment: Just partition the rocks in $m$ pairs, and weight the reference pair against each one. Depending on the result, we discover whether each pair contains 0, 1 or 2 fake rocks.